# Grabbing the first child of a <tr> tag?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, html-parsing, web-scraping, hpple

Currently I'm following Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2899-how-to-parse-html-on-ios) dealing with parsing html on ios. Everything is explained perfectly and according to this tree:

[image]
<sub>(source: [raywenderlich.com](https://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Tutorials-tree-700x303.png))</sub>

they extract the title and url tag for each tutorial.

This is how they create an array to hold their Tutorial object:

```
NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
        // 5
        Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
        [newTutorials addObject:tutorial];

        // 6
        tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];

        // 7
        tutorial.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
    }
```

Now here is my question. I'm currently trying this out on my site. The problem is that I don't know how to get the 4th child of every `<tr>` tag.

Here is my html tree.

[image]

I'm trying to only get that fourth  child from every  tag. But I don't know how to approach it.

Would this be correct?

```
        // 6
        tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];

        // 7
        tutorial.amount = [[element fourthChild] objectForKey:@"td"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use children property to do so :)

First you need to reach out to required  tag to get all  in element children. To do so you can set xpath query like this one: **div[@id='main']/table[@class='bodytext']/tbody/tr**

Then you can get the fourth child using children property. Here is the sample code.

```
//3
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='main']/table[@class='bodytext']/tbody/tr";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

// 4
NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
// 5
Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
[newTutorials addObject:tutorial];

// 6
TFHppleElement *trTag = [[element children] objectAtIndex:3];

tutorial.title = [trTag content];
```

Hope this helps